# SOLR MLT too slow

Tags: solr

I have a SOLR query using MoreLikeThis to get similar docs. But when trying to do some performance tests (using jmeter) and running 50 clients, it is incredibly slow (like 2-3 requests/second). It almost does not matter which type of instance is used (in AWS I tried m3.xlarge 4cpu,16GB as well as m3.2xlarge 8cpu/30GB). Does anybody see a potential problem or some hint for me?

```
/mlt?fl=*,score
&q=DocID:1234
&wt=json
&mlt=true
&mlt.fl=JobID Field1 Field2
&mlt.mintf=1
&q=*,score
&sort=score desc
&fq=!Field3:3
&rows=10
&fq=(!join from=Field1 to=Field1)DocID:1234
&fq=(!join from=Field2 to=Field2)DocID:1234
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after some investigation I was able to find the problem. We accidentally updated all documents to the same content (all fields were equal) and then it was quite difficult for SOLR to work :)